# Show only historical merged branches and my unmerged branches in git log

Tags: git

So my team is growing, and my new colleagues are all committing loads more code collectively than they used to. What I would like is a `git log` command that only shows unmerged branches with my commits in, but does show the full merge history of the branch I'm on.

So, say I use this command

```
git log --all --date=short --graph --pretty=format:"%h%d [%aN] %s" --decorate
```

and see something like:

```
* 0001 (HEAD -> branch-1) [me] ...
| * 0002 (branch-2) [me] ...
|/
| * 0003 (origin/someone-elses-branch, someone-elses-branch) [someone-else] ...
|/
* 0004 (origin/master, master) [someone-else] Merge branch 'another-other-branch'
|\
| * 0005 (origin/another-other-branch) [someone-else] ...
|/
* 0006
```

I want to be able to run a command to see just my unmerged branches, but other people's merged branches in the history:

```
$ git lg-my-branches
* 0001 (HEAD -> branch-1) [me] ...
| * 0002 (branch-2) [me] ...
|/
* 0004 (origin/master, master) [someone-else] Merge branch 'another-other-branch'
|\
| * 0005 (origin/another-other-branch) [someone-else] ...
|/
* 0006
```

And the key thing is that the unmerged `seomeone-elses-branch` is now not showing in the output, but the history of `another-other-branch`, which has been merged, is showing.

Is there a way to do this?